# getting a value from an image in C#

Tags: c#, image, int

I am creating a project where random images show when i click a button and the total of the images (dice) will have to be guessed. I already have down the random image generating and keeping track of the persons amount of rolls. However; I cant figure out how to make a dice (image) have a certain value. Like dice 5 shows and has a value of 4. The person puts there guess in the guessBx and clicks on the guessBtn and it will pop up if they are correct or not.

Here is my code as of now:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace PetalsAroundTheRose
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
public Form1()
{
InitializeComponent();
    }
    int a = 0;
    int diceRoll;
    int diceImage;
    int diceValue;

    private void btnRoll_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        picBx1.Image = imageList1.Images[random.Next(1, 6)];
        picBx2.Image = imageList1.Images[random.Next(1, 6)];
        picBx3.Image = imageList1.Images[random.Next(1, 6)];
        picBx4.Image = imageList1.Images[random.Next(1, 6)];

        a++;
        txtBxRolls.Text = a.ToString();

        //each dice seperate
        //dice 1
        diceRoll = 1;
        diceImage = imageList1.Images[(1)];
        diceValue = 0;

        //dice 2
        diceRoll = 1;
        diceImage = imageList1.Images[(2)];
        diceValue = 0;

        //dice 3
        diceRoll = 1;
        diceImage = imageList1.Images[(3)];
        diceValue = 2;

        //dice 4
        diceRoll = 1;
        diceImage = imageList1.Images[(4)];
        diceValue = 0;

        //dice 5
        diceRoll = 1;
        diceImage = imageList1.Images[(5)];
        diceValue = 4;
    }

    private void guessBx_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
}
}
}
```

On my design I have btnRoll for rolling the dice. guessBx for entering the guess, btnGuess, txtBxCorrect for the amount correct they got, and txtBxResult to say if they are correct or not

The images are in an imageList

Comment: Can you explain more. are images the image of each side of dice? and you want to check if the image and number entered are same?

Comment: yes, each image is a side of the die. After the images are "rolled" be able to check if the value of the images that are shown are correct. similar to the petals are the rose game.

Comment: Pick a random number from (1-7].  That will tell you the value of the roll of the die.  Use that as the index into your ImageList depending on how they are listed

Comment: ...also use one single random instance for the entire app - do not create a new one on each click

Comment: Instead of using an ImageList, make a custom class with an Image and Int32 as properties to put your image and its value into, and then make a List<> of those as source for your random selections. Then you can get out both the image and the value of the chosen objects.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly i create a class with these two properties

```
public class Dice
{
    public int Indexer { get; set; }
    public string PhotoPath { get; set; }

    public Dice(int indexer, string photoPath)
    {
        Indexer = indexer;
        PhotoPath = photoPath;
    }
}
```

After that i put in my form the picture boxes and then i created two methods 
the first one:

```
public void SetUp()
    {         
        for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
        {
            temp = random.Next(1, 6);
            dice = new Die(temp, "C:\\Users\\giorg\\Desktop\\dice\\dice" + temp + ".PNG");
            dices.Add(dice); // list<Dice> dices = new list<Dice>();
        }
    }
```

and the second one:

```
public  void RollDices()
    {
        //this is not necessary but if you want to keep a sum of dices keep 
        //it
        var count = 0;
        foreach (var dice in dices)
        {
            count += dice.Indexer;
        }
        //pictureboxes 2-7 are guess boxes
        if(textBox2.Text.Equals(dices[0].Indexer.ToString()))
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(dices[0].PhotoPath);

        if (textBox3.Text.Equals(dices[1].Indexer.ToString()))
            pictureBox2.Image = Image.FromFile(dices[1].PhotoPath);

        if (textBox4.Text.Equals(dices[2].Indexer.ToString()))
            pictureBox3.Image = Image.FromFile(dices[2].PhotoPath);

        if (textBox5.Text.Equals(dices[3].Indexer.ToString()))
            pictureBox4.Image = Image.FromFile(dices[3].PhotoPath);

        if (textBox6.Text.Equals(dices[4].Indexer.ToString()))
            pictureBox5.Image = Image.FromFile(dices[4].PhotoPath);

        if (textBox7.Text.Equals(dices[5].Indexer.ToString()))
            pictureBox6.Image = Image.FromFile(dices[5].PhotoPath);    
    }
```

Put these two methods to your button click event and you are ok...
Inform me if you are ok with this approach.

Comment: since the images are not on my PC they are in a image list, souldn't I put for the new die... (imageList1.Images)??

Comment: Why you don't use the class dice which has value(indexer in my sample) and photopath and then add  "dices" into a list<> instead of using imageList? Is there any reason?